# Watson Information Encoding

Tags: data, artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, information

[IBM's Watson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson_(computer)) has a lot of book information encoded into a 'database' that Watson searches in real time. Does anyone know how that information is coded? It seems hard to imagine how humans could type in all of those rules.

Comment: Have you looked at the AMA they did on Reddit? There might be something there. http://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/related/fnfg3/by_request_we_are_the_ibm_research_team_that/

Answer (score 8):

The heart of Watson is IBM DeepQA software. We find some answers on it's [FAQ](http://www.research.ibm.com/deepqa/faq.shtml):

> **Q: What data is stored in Watson?**
>
> A: All of Watson's data will be
>   self-contained. Watson will perform
>   without a connection to the web or any
>   external resource. The vast majority
>   of Watson's data will be a wide
>   variety of natural language text. Some
>   structured (formal knowledgebase's)
>   and semi-structured data (tagged text)
>   is also included mostly to help
>   interpret text and refine answers.
>   Exactly which data will be used for
>   competing on Jeopardy! will be
>   revealed at a later date, but the
>   specific content and how to analyze
>   and manage it are part of the research
>   agenda
>
> **Q: Does DeepQA use UIMA?**
>
> A: Yes. UIMA is a
>   standard framework for building
>   applications that perform deep
>   analysis on unstructured content,
>   including natural language text,
>   speech, images and video. IBM
>   contributed UIMA to open-source (see
>   the Apache UIMA web site) to help
>   facilitate and accelerate work in deep
>   content analytics. UIMA is also now an
>   OASIS standard. UIMA-AS implements
>   UIMA on asynchronous messaging
>   middleware. DeepQA and the Watson
>   system uses UIMA-AS as its principal
>   infrastructure for assembling,
>   scaling-out and deploying all its
>   analytic components.

UIMA is probably the key. From [Apache UIMA](http://uima.apache.org/) description:

> Unstructured Information Management
>   applications are software systems that
>   analyze large volumes of unstructured
>   information in order to discover
>   knowledge that is relevant to an end
>   user. An example UIM application might
>   ingest plain text and identify
>   entities, such as persons, places,
>   organizations; or relations, such as
>   works-for or located-at.
>
> UIMA enables applications to be
>   decomposed into components, for
>   example "language identification" =>
>   "language specific segmentation" =>
>   "sentence boundary detection" =>
>   "entity detection (person/place names
>   etc.)". Each component implements
>   interfaces defined by the framework
>   and provides self-describing metadata
>   via XML descriptor files. The
>   framework manages these components and
>   the data flow between them. Components
>   are written in Java or C++; the data
>   that flows between components is
>   designed for efficient mapping between
>   these languages.

[This](https://blogs.apache.org/foundation/entry/apache_innovation_bolsters_ibm_s) Apache press release has some more information:

> Hundreds of Apache UIMA Annotators and
>   thousands of algorithms help Watson
>   –which runs disconnected from the
>   Internet– access vast databases to
>   simultaneously comprehend clues and
>   formulate answers. Watson then
>   analyzes 500 gigabytes of preprocessed
>   information to match potential
>   meanings for the question and a
>   potential answer to the question.
>   Helping Watson do this is:
>
> 1. Apache UIMA: standards-based
>      frameworks, infrastructure and
>      components that facilitate the
>      analysis and annotation of an array of
>      unstructured content (such as text,
>      audio and video). Watson uses Apache
>      UIMA for real-time content analytics
>      and natural language processing, to
>      comprehend clues, find possible
>      answers, gather supporting evidence,
>      score each answer, compute its
>      confidence in each answer, and improve
>      contextual understanding (machine
>      learning) – all under 3 seconds.
> 2. Apache Hadoop: software framework that
>      enables data-intensive distributed
>      applications to work with thousands of
>      nodes and petabytes of data. A
>      foundation of Cloud computing, Apache
>      Hadoop enables Watson to access, sort,
>      and process data in a massively
>      parallel system (90+ server
>      cluster/2,880 processor cores/16
>      terabytes of RAM/4 terabytes of disk
>      storage).
>
> The Watson system uses UIMA as its
>   principal infrastructure for component
>   interoperability and makes extensive
>   use of the UIMA-AS scale-out
>   capabilities that can exploit modern,
>   highly parallel hardware
>   architectures. UIMA manages all work
>   flow and communication between
>   processes, which are spread across the
>   cluster. Apache Hadoop manages the
>   task of preprocessing Watson's
>   enormous information sources by
>   deploying UIMA pipelines as Hadoop
>   mappers, running UIMA analytics.

Pretty interesting :)

Comment: Indeed, pretty interesting! Very nice answer.